# Re-enable SSMS Addin

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms-addin

I'm sure this is very simple but I can't seem to find an answer to this at the moment and my googling powers have returned nothing.

I previously had an issue with an Addin and SSMS gave me the option to disable it (which I took). I have since reinstalled the plugin but it still does not appear as I previously disabled it.

Does anyone know where I can find the 'Add-In Manager' in SSMS 2008 R2 like in Visual studio?

Comment: Did SSMS asked if you want to remove the item from the menu? AFAIK, if that is the case, you have to reinstall the add-in or temper with the registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2008 versions of SSMS you have to check this registry key:
Key="HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\AddIns\"
You will find there 1 entry per installed add-in. Every add-in entry has setting:
"LoadBehavior". Set it to "1" to make SSMS load add-in at start-up.

Comment: Thank you sir, this sorted it.

Comment: Of course, on 64-bit systems this will be in the equivalent path under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node...

Answer (score 2):

You can check and see if your add-in is located in either of these directories:

```
%PROGRAMDATA%\Application Data\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins\

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\MSEnvShared\Addins\
```

I believe disabling an add-in will simply remove/move it from one or the other of those directories, or possibly change the extension.

SSMS doesn't have any official support from MS for add-in functionality, unfortunately, so is lacking in tools to manage the add-ins. They have also stated that they won't support your installation of SSMS if you have extensions installed for it. Read here for more: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265567/ssms-allow-support-for-addins-as-in-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise they don't support add-ins. And those folders look fine so into the registry I dive then :)