# Visual Studio 2017 IntelliSense no error highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Today I updated my Visual Studio 2017 to the current version 15.3.3.
Afterwards code errors are not highlighted in the code editor anymore. 
What I've tried so far:

- Resetting user settings
- Deleting the .vs folder from my solution
- Deleting the visual studio folder from my AppData folder
- Repairing VS with the Visual Studio Installer
- Clean installation of Visual Studio (so no VS extensions or plugins installed)

In new created projects IntelliSense and the error highlighting is working as expected. I have this issue only in my existing ASP.NET 4.5 projects. 
So this is obviously connected with some project settings. Then again my colleagues are working with the same project and same VS version with no issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Felix, It seems this issue is more relates to your VS or your computer, have a try the following 1. Open CMD as admin and navigate to the VS 2017 installation folder and run the command: devenv /safemode to check if the installed extensions caused this issue. 2. Click Start and scroll down to the Visual Studio 2017 folder, expand it, run the ‘Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017’ as administrator and run the command: devenv /setup and devenv /resetuserdata 3. Perform a clean boot: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows and test

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, none of your tips solved my problem.

Comment: please try to create a new account of your computer, then login with this new account and run VS to have a test.

Comment: Based on [my experience with IntelliSense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301772), getting a whole new computer doesn't guarantee your issue will be solved. It must be some configuration external to the .NET development suite. My JavaScript IntelliSense has always been broken as well, but fortunately I do minimal JS coding.